# Can Ubuntu read music and data CDs Burnt on Windows

Tags: dvd-audio

I'm seriously considering switching from Winows to Ubuntu as I seriously dislike Windows 8.1 and have an old eMachines EL-1600. I believe this old net top will run 32 bit Ubuntu
just fine. (Intel Atom 230 1.6 GHz processor and 1 GB ram with Intel 945G Express Chipset)
I believe Ubuntu 12.04LTS will run perfectly, but I'm hoping the latest LTS release will as well. However, that now brings me to my question.

I've burnt a whole pile of MP3 DVDss using Win XP, and I was wondering if I install Ubuntu
can they still be read? I just want to copy the MP3s back from the DVDs back to the 
main music folder in Ubuntu. I have no intention of installing WINE (viruses) and
will beusing the pre-instlled and native Ubuntu apps such as Libre Office and Firefox which I'm already using in Windows. I also use a PPoE broadband connection so that won't be a problem either. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I did a similar exercise when I moved from windows to ubuntu. I backed up all my mp3, photos, movies etc on dvd and external hard drive. The copied them back to my pc and had all my files again.

I would also suggest that post installation that you install a few extras to complete you ubuntu installation. Using **Ubuntu Software Center**

Install **Ubuntu Restricted Extras** for media codecs, for codecs that are not installed by default. With this installed, you can play mp3, mp4, avi etc...

**Tweak Unity** will let you tweak the appearace of unity (ubuntu)

**VLC** media player just because!

Lastly to enable encrypted DVD playback in ubuntu you need to install **libdvdread4** once installed open **terminal** and run the following command;

```
sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh
```

this will download the necessary dvd libraries.